# vaadin localization for enums

Tags: java, localization, enums, vaadin

Im currently working on a project using vaadin.. so far everything is working except for localizing abstract select components (option group ,combobox, dropdowns etc) wherein the select items are from enum types. I used the approach of using Containers:

```
private Container buildFundTransferTypeContainer() {
        Container container = new IndexedContainer();
        container.addContainerProperty("label", String.class, "");
        container.addContainerProperty("value", FundTransferType.class, null);
        for (FundTransferType type : FundTransferType.values()) {
            Object id = container.addItem();
            container.getContainerProperty(id, "label").setValue(
                    MessageResource.getLocalizedString(type.name()));
            container.getContainerProperty(id, "value").setValue(type);
        }
        return container;
    }
```

then the field is set by:

```
fundTransferTypeField.setContainerDataSource(buildFundTransferTypeContainer());
fundTransferTypeField.setItemCaptionPropertyId("label");
```

so that the property "label" will be used for display. so far this is working in terms of displaying the localized values in the browser, however i get a

```
com.vaadin.data.Buffered$SourceException
...
Caused by: com.vaadin.data.Buffered$SourceException
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.commit(AbstractField.java:261)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Form.commit(Form.java:339)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.data.Property$ConversionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.novenix.tgsmango.core.enums.FundTransferType.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.MethodProperty.convertValue(MethodProperty.java:697)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.MethodProperty.setValue(MethodProperty.java:666)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.commit(AbstractField.java:256)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sample.project.core.enums.FundTransferType.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.MethodProperty.convertValue(MethodProperty.java:690)
    ... 37 more
```

when the commit is called on the form. How should localized values be handled on these vaadin components. Thanks for the replies

Comment: So does it work if you don't localize the label Strings? Can you show me your FundTransferType definition?

Comment: We need your FundTransferType class to solve this. The stacktrace seems to point to an error in that class

Comment: Thanks for your replies.. i was able to solve this issue a while ago. and i did it by adding the actual enum (field.addItem(enum1)) then setting the item caption with the localized string (field.setItemCaption(enum1, Localizer.localize(enum1.name()))).. again thanks a lot.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved the case. Could you please submit that as an answer? That would help someone with the same type of problem to find the answer with less effort.

Comment: ive posted the solution than i used.. thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that i used.
on the field factory or when whenever you create the field,

```
ComboBox accountStatusChoice = new ComboBox();

accountStatusChoice.setCaption(MessageResource.getLocalizedString("caption.accountStatus"));
accountStatusChoice.setRequired(true);
accountStatusChoice.setRequiredError(MessageResource.getLocalizedString("error.required.accountStatus"));
accountStatusChoice.setImmediate(true);

for (AccountStatus accountStatus : AccountStatus.values()) {
    accountStatusChoice.addItem(accountStatus);
    accountStatusChoice.setItemCaption(accountStatus, MessageResource.getLocalizedString(accountStatus.name()));
}

return accountStatusChoice;
```

in this  code, the MessageResource.getLocalizedString("resourceKey") is my util class to retrieve the localized strings via resource bundle. when adding the contents of the combo box (or whichever abstractSelect component you want to use), use the addItem to add the object value you wish to use, and use the setItemCaption(itemId, captionString) to set the caption visible to the user.

The beanItem that you will use for your form will simply need to have a property of the Enum (in this case a AccountStatus instance variable). when the commit is called in the form, it will no longer throw the com.vaadin.data.Buffered$SourceException.